# Python: Is there a natsort variant that can process numeric data in any language?

Tags: python

I'm trying to generate street indexes for maps in an internationalized way, with "natural" sort orders for numbered streets. This works well as long as numbers use ASCII digits only, but not so much when using digits from other scripts, like e.g. Farsi here, with ۱=1 and ۲=2

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import locale
from natsort import natsort_keygen, ns


locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'fa_IR.UTF-8')

streets = [ 
        "2 street",     
        "1 street",
        "12 street",
        "11 street",
        "۲ street",
        "۱ street",
        "۱۲ street",
        "۱۱ street",
]

sl = sorted(streets, key = natsort_keygen(alg=ns.LOCALE|ns.IGNORECASE|ns.TYPESAFE))

for name in sl:
    print(name)
```

Expected result:

```
1 street
۱ street
2 street
۲ street
11 street
12 street
۱۱ street
۱۲ street
```

Actual result:

```
۱۱ street
۱۲ street
1 street
۱ street
2 street
۲ street
11 street
12 street
```

Comment: Turns out support for this is almost there in natsort, just requires some minor fixes:

https://github.com/SethMMorton/natsort/issues/52

https://github.com/SethMMorton/natsort/issues/51

Answer (score 0):

Python's `int()` is able to convert correctly so you could role your own:

```
def natsorted(l):
    # For simple string lists containing numbers
    return sorted(l, key=lambda x: [int(d) if d else l for d, l in re.findall(r'(\d+)|(\D+)', x)])

streets = [ 
        "2 street",     
        "1 street",
        "12 street",
        "11 street",
        "۲ street",
        "۱ street",
        "۱۲ street",
        "۱۱ street",
]

sl = natsorted(streets) #, key = natsort_keygen(alg=ns.LOCALE|ns.IGNORECASE|ns.TYPESAFE))

for name in sl:
    print(name)
```

This would give you:

```
1 street
۱ street
2 street
۲ street
11 street
۱۱ street
12 street
۱۲ street
```

Comment: It looked good in simple tests, but when trying it on actual data I ended  up with the following: [natsort]{http://php-groupies.de/test-natsort.png} vs. [your code]{http://php-groupies.de/test-your-code.png}

Comment: Can you provide some more test cases in your question (in text form) so I can copy/paste them?

Comment: Also try the script again, I have improved the algorithm.